# Calculating temperature of gas

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have the question "A container had 6 moles of an ideal gas. In an experiment, the pressure of the gas and its volume were measured at constant temperature. The following readings were obtained and plotted on the graph on the next page Determine the gradient of the graph. Hence calculate the temperature of the gas."

Here is the graph:

[image]

Here is my attempt is this correct ? :

[image]

Comment: Carmel school??

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct, but your gradient calculation is wrong. Looking at the first and last data points on the graph, $\Delta y$ is approximately 140,000 Pa and $\Delta x$ is approx. 10 $m^{-3}$, so your gradient should be about 14,000.